# How do real graphics devices get referenced in xorg.conf?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, xorg

I'm having trouble figuring out how an actual graphics device gets referenced from the xorg.conf file.

Ubuntu 22.04 MATE

Using zrandr I get two outputs:
None-1:
HDMI-1-1:

(Incidentally None-1 is not physically wired to anything (unwired internal MIPI display) and is the default for some reason and I can't get Xorg to display to the HDMI port)

So in what section do I reference HDMI-1-1 and make it the default?

I have been reading this : https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/x-power-tools/9780596101954/ch04.html

But I don;t see the connection between any of the sections and a real device!

Followup:

I have tried adding some monitor sectionsd to the xorg.conf but there has been no change in xrandr.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DRM Graphics Acclerated"

    ## Use modesetting and glamor
        Driver      "modesetting"
        Option      "AccelMethod"    "glamor"     ### "glamor" to enable 3D acceleration, "none" to disable.
        Option      "DRI"            "2"
        Option      "Dri2Vsync"      "true"
        Option      "TripleBuffer"   "True"
    ## End glamor configuration

EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
        SubSection "Display"
            Depth 24
        EndSubSection
    Monitor "Default Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Default Monitor"
    Option "Monitor-HDMI-1-1" "HDMI monitor"
    Option "Primary"
    Option "Enable" "1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Unused Monitor"
    Option "Monitor-None-1" "None monitor"
    Option "Ignore" "1"
EndSection
```

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 720 x 576, maximum 4096 x 4096
None-1 connected primary 720x576+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   720x576       60.00*+
HDMI-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67
```